# Make web menu smart, animation / viewport / on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just started to do a new website, all things works great but I was not able to make a good menu:

I want an animation which always start when I go up and the menu changes, but its not working very fine, because I need this animation every time I go back up.

Thats the first problem, the second problem is about an Eventhandler I want to use for the different menus, because when I scroll the menu goes a little bit smaller and up again it is bigger. But when I scroll and then make a reload the menu returns to the big one altough Im not up again.

The last problem is about the browser width, I want that the scripts are running if the viewport is big enough otherwise it shouldnt run.

The menu I've created is a bit like the page of Oxford: https://ox.ac.uk

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 120) {
      $(".header").addClass("small");
      $("#logo").css('display', 'none');
      $(".site-table").css('display', 'none');
      $("#b1-scroll").css('display', 'block');
      $(".site-nav").css('top', '14px');
      $(".site-nav").css('left', '25px');
      $(".second-site-nav").css('top', '28px');
      $(".second-site-nav").css('right', '85px');

    } else {
      $(".header").removeClass("small");
      $("#logo").css('display', 'block');
      $(".site-table").css('display', 'block');
      $("#b1-scroll").css('display', 'none');
      $(".site-nav").css('top', '50px');
      $(".site-nav").css('left', '175px');
      $(".second-site-nav").css('top', '100px');
      $(".second-site-nav").css('right', '20px');
    }
  });
});
```

If its possible i want all the code running in this file.

I Hope you guys can help me with this problems altough they are quit difficult!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a technique called 'Affix'! Check this out:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp (A bootstrap implementation)! Let me know if it is want you want!

Comment: Thanks! its a good thing, but i can solve this already, more important is an eventhandler for the size of the menu (if I'm up it should be big, while scrolling small (also when i reload))and the animation which should start every time i go up again, something like fadein or something similar

Comment: Not clear what you mean... You want the menu to be smaller while scrolling?